# issue mocking spring jdbctemplate with @Autowired

Tags: java, spring

I use mockito as a mock object library. I am unit testing DAOs.

DAOs expect JdbcTemplate to be injected through @Autowired. Hence, there are no setter methods for JDBC Template in DAOs which unit tests can call.

I have the following test spring application context:

```
<b:beans 
    xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <b:bean id="mockito" class="org.mockito.Mockito" />
    <b:bean 
        id="mockJdbcTemplate"
        factory-bean="mockito"
        factory-method="mock">
        <b:constructor-arg value="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate"/>
    </b:bean>
</b:beans>
```

I was expecting that at test execution time, spring will create mock jdbctemplate instance and autowire it to DAO.

But that doesn't happen - instead I just get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:920)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:789)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:474)
    ... 42 more
```

Has anyone had success with this approach before?

Thanks.

Comment: I fail to see the point in mocking JdbcTemplate. What's the point of testing a DAO by mocking the JdbcTemplate? What will your test test?

Comment: Well, we have a separate project for DAO layer and this is the only project with 0% code coverage as we skipped writing unit tests for DAO as most of the method bodies are one liners (this.jdbcTemplate.query or update) - but during external audit, this (no test coverage) was picked upon and so I am writing unit tests to tick the checkboxes...

Comment: I think this DAO project should use integration tests, not unit tests. So you should create a test database and check if DAO methods produce correct results. Also, have a look at DbUnit.

Comment: I cannot use embedded database because of various reasons (Sybase ASE query syntax support lacking)..and testing with embedded database will not be true test either...Using a standalone test database slows down the test execution..and we have 7 developers and one CI server...so tests wont execute in isolation...

Comment: So in fact, the tests won't test anything at all, but just be used to artificially increase the coverage. Sorry, but this is really stupid. You might as well use the real JdbcTemplate and catch and ignore any exception in your test.

Comment: This is not really about DAO ...its a spring technical question: How do you autowire and inject a property with an object returned by instance factory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the factory method `mock` which returns generic type. After erasure, the spring is not able to deduct object type, try to provide explicit object type by `class` attribute.

```
public MockitoMockFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<?>
{
    private Class<?> objectType;

    @Override public Object getObject()
    {
        return Mockito.mock(objectType);
    }
    public void setObjectType(Class<?> objectType)
    {
        this.objectType=objectType;
    }
    @Override public Class<?> getObjectType()
    {
        return objectType;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Kan: I tried specifying class attribute - didn't work (no additional errors though).

Comment: Oh, right _If the "factory-bean" attribute is present, the "class" attribute is not used_. Then I don't see any option other than creating a `FactoryBean` implementation which will return correct object type by `getObjectType` method.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few other techniques that can help with your testing concerns:

Using your real database:

Spring Framework support for [Testing](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html) allows you to start transactions during setup, and roll them back in the teardown, so the database isn't littered with test data.  For complex setup [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) can assist with this.  As you pointed out, this takes longer to run than unit tests.  That is why developers often separate integration tests into a separate suite that is run as a build step rather than part of a developer's build.

Using MockRunner:

MockRunner is a library to create fake JDBC components where you populate the result set data, and JdbcTemplate doesn't know the difference.  I'm not sure you can create a MockDataSource using just Spring without writing some helper classes

Using Mockito inside of a test without Spring wiring:

Mockito is best used for unit testing.  So your DAO tests wouldn't be wired using Spring, you would create a unit test where you create the mocked JdbcTemplate that you manually inject into your DAO.

If you are trying to test more than just the DAO individually, and want to see how several components fit together a real integration test, then mocking a database will hide the real issues that pop up with your real database.  If you just care that your individual DAOs behave properly with mock output from JdbcTemplates then using Mockito or MockRunner will allow you to do that.